# Need to Get the rid of many if's

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I have variable in my java script which is global. Now i got different value each time when inner function call. I need to create a option tags with selected value as in attribute and one for without selected value based on the variable. I guess this is more confusing let me give you a example.

```
var a1 = "a1c" // default value but may change

if(a1 == "all")
{
    var allstatusdefault = '<option value="all" selected="selected">All</option>';
}
else
{
    var allstatusdefault = '<option value="all" >All</option>';
}

if(a1 == "a1b")
{
    var allstatusdefault1 = '<option value="a1b" selected="selected">a1b</option>';
}
else
{
    var allstatusdefault1 = '<option value="a1b" >a1b</option>';
}

if(a1 == "a1bc")
{
    var allstatusdefault2 = '<option value="a1bc" selected="selected">a1bc</option>';
}
else
{
    var allstatusdefault2 = '<option value="a1bc" >a1bc</option>';
}
```

This is just sample but i have to generate lot of option tag with different values.I don't want to write to many if ..anybody have any other idea?

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish something like this. Please provide some additional context to your specific issue.

Comment: I guess the above code explain everything. Just need to get the rid of to many if's. Every time i am getting different value and based on that value i have to select which item i need to select as default. So bottom line is one value two option tag.

Comment: Add the options and than at the end, select the one.

Answer (score 3):

Extract common code, I see a lot of duplication here.

```
var a1 = "a1c";

function buildOption(id) {
    var selected = (a1 == id? ' selected="selected"' : '');
    return '<option value="' + id + '"' + selected + '>' + id + '</option>';
}

var allstatusdefault =  buildOption('all');
var allstatusdefault1 = buildOption('a1b');
var allstatusdefault2 = buildOption('a1bc');
```

Comment: Don't you need a `return` in `buildOption`?

Comment: @DourHighArch: of course, too much [tag:scala], fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From what i can deduct here is what you should do

```
var default1 = '<option value="'+a1+'" selected="selected">'+a1+'</option>';
var default2 = '<option value="'+a2+'" selected="selected">'+a2+'</option>';
```

Since the value of `a1` is reused in the string, might as well just set it right away instead of using multiple if statements.

Note: when you have many if statement its the perfect opportunity to use a switch statement

Comment: You don't handle the selected/not selected part.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, learn about [`switch...case`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). In your case, it looks like you could possibly simply use the variable itself in the formation of the strings by concatenating the variable to a string.

Comment: Given that each `if`/`else` combination sets a distinct variable and that either will execute, `switch` will probably a bit of a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var a1 = "a1bc" // default value but may change
    switch(a1)
        {
        case "all" : allstatusdefault = '<option value="all" selected="selected">All</option>';break;
        case "a1b" : allstatusdefault = '<option value="a1b" selected="selected">a1b</option>'; break;
        case "a1bc" :  allstatusdefault = '<option value="a1bc" selected="selected">a1bc</option>'; break;
        default :  allstatusdefault = '<option value="all" >All</option>';break;
        }
    window.alert(allstatusdefault); ​
```

Comment: I guess i am not sure how the above code is working.. Because if allstatusdefault don't have value "a1b" than i need to generate the option tag with its value like <option value="a1b" >All</option>. In this case default whould be always value with "all". I don't want that..

Comment: It's clear you don't understand it because of your many ifs, which can lead to unexpected results.
What happens here is that the string a1 is evaulated. If it matches any of the strings behind the word `case` then it executes everything between `:` and `;break;` What is behind `default :` is what will happen when the string a1 doesn't match any of the cases.
You can fill in any value you want there.

Answer (score -1):

I think from the way you are writing code you could do one with use jQuery. Create entire HTML first, with all the option values using jQuery object like this :

`var $optionHTML = $('<option value=""> Blahblah </option>')`;
Now you can apply all jquery function to this guy. so you append a new option like this.

`$optionHTML.append('<option>...</option>')`

when you are done with all the option element use jquery selector method to find an element with option having value attribute matching to `a1c` then add attribute `selected` then you are done.

Do let me know if you need some code for starters.

Thanks.

EDIT :

HERE IS THE ANSWER

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src= "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        $(document).ready (function () {
            var value = "test 2";
            $select = $("<select></select>");
            $optionHTML1 = $('<option value="test 1">Test 1</option>');
            $optionHTML2 = $('<option value="test 2">Test 2</option>');
            $optionHTML1.appendTo($select); 
            $optionHTML2.appendTo($select);
            $select.find("[value='test 2']").attr('selected','selected');
            alert($select.html());  
            $("div").append($select);
        });
    </script>
    <style type = "text/css">
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This code will also work even if you have 200 option value in select box. you dont have to apply switch and all it will work fine and it is extensible.

Comment: I am looking for to build a string with all my condition on time of HTML building.. Thanks

Comment: @ravipatel but as you are using option there could be only one value which could be selected from option correct then this solution would wotk.I am currently trying it. thanks.